# How to convert an array to a simpler form using php function

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I am having an array like this

```
$myAllProducts= array(
           0=> array(
               'productName' => "Classmate",
               'productId' => 2
           ),
            1=>array(
                'productName' => "tata",
               'productId' => 3
            ),
            2=>array(
                'productName' => "abcd",
               'productId' => 4
            ),
            1=>array(
                'productName' => "pen",
               'productId' => 7
            ),
        )
```

And I want to convert it to an array like

```
array('Classmate'=>2,
'tata'=>3,
'abcd'=>4,
'pen'=>7)
```

I am doing it like this

```
$productList=array();
foreach($myAllProducts as $record)
            {
                $productsList[$record['productName']]=$record['productId'];
            }
```

**Question:-**
Although I am successfully getting the desired result using my loop but I want to know if it could be done using any built in function or in a much better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5, then you can use the new [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$productList = array_combine(
    array_column(
        $myAllProducts,
        'productName'
    ),
    array_column(
        $myAllProducts,
        'productId'
    )
);
```

or (even simpler)

```
$productList = array_column(
    $myAllProducts, 
    'productId', 
    'productName'
);
```

Comment: sorry but i am using 5.3 :(

Comment: There's a userland implementation of array_column() available at http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/ which would work with earlier versions than 5.5 - but your simple loop is the easiest way of doing it before array_column() was introduced into PHP core

Comment: thanks for letting me know about array_column() sir.